# Pandas apply function - args how is it passed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Cars93_miss.csv')
d = {'Min.Price': np.nanmean, 'Max.Price': np.nanmedian}
df[['Min.Price', 'Max.Price']] = df[['Min.Price', 'Max.Price']].apply(lambda x, d: x.fillna(d[x.name](x)), args=(d, ))
```

`apply(lambda x, d: x.fillna(d[x.name](x)), args=(d, ))` - Am not understanding this part. I know how apply and fillna works but with this args it's confusing.

1. why does args have comma at the end
2. what does the d actually pass -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, `df.apply` function applies a function to the DataFrame's elements. Now this function normally takes only one argument. When you need to use a multi argument function with `df.apply`, you can specify the other arguments with the `args` parameter

From the docstring (`print(pd.DataFrame.apply.__doc__)`)

```
args : tuple
    Positional arguments to pass to `func` in addition to the
    array/series.
```

Here you are using two argument function with `lambda x, d:` therefore you need to specify the 2nd argument with `args=`. Here it is expecting a tuple with the arguments

To put a single element into a tuple, you need to put it into brackets with a trailing comma.

```
print(1)                                                                              
>>>1
print((1,))                                                                           
>>>(1,)
```

To put the variable `d` into a tuple, you need to do `(d,)`

The dictionary contains two separate functions for the two columns with column names as its keys. So `x` being the column passed into the lambda function, `x.name` gives you the column name and `d[x.name]` gives you the function intended for that column name. Then that function is applied to the column.

For the 'Min.Price' column the function is `np.nanmean`. So `d[x.name](x)` is evaluated to `np.nanmean(x)` which gives you the column mean excluding `nan`s. Now you're using the mean value to fill the `nan`s in the original column by doing `x.fillna(d[x.name](x))`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helps

Answer (score 1):

To more directly answer your question:

1. `args` is a tuple, and a single element tuple requires a trailing comma in order to properly be identified as a tuple and not just a parameterized object.
2. `d` is your dictionary, and when it's being passed at the end I believe it is your current list after having the lambda function applied to each element in the dictionary saying that if the element is NaN or N/A (ie Null/missing) then it will fill them with the given value specified. [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
   Hopefully that helps.